# Can I upgrade the memory in a MacBook Pro 2019?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, virtual-memory

my Mac is a MacBook Pro 2019

[image]

[image]

I do not have any information about Mac or cp.

I am using R and I am running a heavy model, but I can not get a result because of lack of memory. Is there any way to fix it, like swap memory?

Please help me step by step if it is possible
If it isn't possible let me know

Comment: *Mac Pro and Macbook Pro are two different things*. "I am using R and I am running a heavy model" **What does that mean?** Have you you done a web search for -  upgrade Macbook Pro memory - for your model number? **Please revise your question to more clear and detailed**.

Comment: @AlaskaMan u mean I should mention what I am running?

Comment: solve.Qp for a matrix with 36944*36944 size

Comment: The MacTracker app gives details for all macs - very handy for questions like this...

Comment: @AlaskaMan [R](https://www.r-project.org/) is a programming language widely used in statistics and data science. It is the first result I get if I search (Google or DuckDuckGo) for `R`!

Answer (score 5):

The memory in the 2019 MBP (two Thunderbolt 3 ports) is soldered to the motherboard, and is not user-upgradeable.

Comment: If memory were upgradable, then the "About this Mac" window we see in the OP would have "Memory" between "Storage" and "Support".